# What is actually measured by means of a diffraction grating?

Tags: special-relativity, optics

According to elementary optics it would appear that a diffraction grating measures the wavelength of the incident light.
But if that were the case, it would be possible to measure independently both the wave length $\lambda$ of the light coming from a star and its frequency $\nu$ (at least in principle by means of a clock).
This would constitute a measurement of the one way speed of light, which is commonly considered impossible.

So I ask again: what is actually measured by means of a diffraction grating?

Comment: Not sure I understood what you meant... why would a measurement of the speed of light be impossible?

Comment: How can you measure the speed of light knowing the frequency and wavelength? I mean, yes, its defined as $c=\lambda f$ but thats from deriving the equations and defining a wave. How do you propose to actually derive the speed of light ($distance/time$, I suppose you meant distance being the distance to the star, and time, the time it took for the light to get here) from those 2 quantities?

Comment: @qwyxivi The OP specifically mentioned the [one-way speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light)

Comment: Oh, now I'm seeing the point of this question. I think it's due to the fact that the diffraction grating/interferometer has some length in a different direction, so you are actually calculating a round trip phase between the two (or more) slits? But seeing that I just learned about this topic, I'm not exactly confident in that haha.